# "System.AccessViolationException was unhandled" error when writing video using emgu CV

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, emgucv

I'm trying to capture a video using EMGU CV in visual studio 2010, but when it executes the line

```
video.WriteFrame<Bgr, byte>(marked);
```

i get the follwing error:

System.AccessViolationException was unhandled

Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

```
private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Capture camera = new Capture();
        if (camera == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("can't find a camera", "error");
        }
        double fps = camera.GetCaptureProperty(CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
        double cpHeight = camera.GetCaptureProperty(CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
        double cpWidth = camera.GetCaptureProperty(CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
        double fourcc = camera.GetCaptureProperty(CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC);
        CvInvoke.cvNamedWindow("camera");
        Image<Bgr, byte> temp = camera.QueryFrame();
        //路径
        SaveFileDialog SaveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
        SaveFileDialog1.FileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss");
        SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "Image Files(*.avi)|*.avi|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        if (SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("START RECORD，ESC TO STOP");
        }
        VideoWriter video = new VideoWriter(SaveFileDialog1.FileName, (int)fourcc, 15, 800, 600, true);
        while (temp != null)
        {
            CvInvoke.cvShowImage("camera", temp.Ptr);
            temp = camera.QueryFrame();
            int c = CvInvoke.cvWaitKey(20);
            Image<Bgr, byte> marked = faceDetection(temp);
            video.WriteFrame<Bgr, byte>(marked);
            if (c == 27) break;
        }
        video.Dispose();
        camera.Dispose();
        CvInvoke.cvDestroyWindow("camera");
    }
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Thanks

Evan

Answer (score 0):

after reorder the following lines its worked for me perfectly. also check is **marked** is not null. if marked is null then it will rise the access violation error.

```
while (temp != null)
{
    CvInvoke.cvShowImage("camera", temp.Ptr);

    Image<Bgr, byte> marked = faceDetection(temp);
    video.WriteFrame<Bgr, byte>(marked);

    int c = CvInvoke.cvWaitKey(20);
    if (c == 27) break;

    temp = camera.QueryFrame();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late answer but maybe someone will find it helpful.

I'm fighting with this error myself now (in different circumstances) and it looks like it's a problem of trying to include 32-bit components in my project on 64-bit Windows.

On 32-bit system it runs perfectly, on 64-bit I have "System.AccessViolationException was unhandled"

Sadly not much can be done in my case, just giving up with component and doing it some other way

Maybe it's a problem here too. What is VideoWriter, doesn't seem like standard .NET class?